# What logic is behind the fabric (iOS) detection of jail broken devices

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics for iOS in my app...I have jailbroken detection code which searches for some files and promptly exits the app if the device is found to be jailbroken.

I am consolidating my research on jailbroke detection techniques here:
1) Search for files like "/Applications/Cydia.app", "/Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib" etc.. 
2) Checking for the permission to write to system directories  
3) Checking for the singerIdentity of info.plist

Among the above techniques, I generally use the first one for all of my apps. I am thinking to implement the other 2 techniques too, but before that **I want to know if someone is aware of the Fabric(Crashlytics) detection technique ?? Because it identified few devices as jailbroken in one of my live app. So want to know if Fabric implements something other than the above 3 techniques.**

Comment: I don't thing they will say anything at all

Comment: Well yeah I was assuming the same that they dont expose their logic..